# Struggeling with Nvidia dualscreen

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu

I have a GTX550 TI in my PC and xubuntu 12.10. I Installed the newest driver from Nvidia's website and everything works fine. Except for one thing.

I have two screens, a small CRT one and a big LCD one. The small CRT is to the left of the big LCD. The big LCD needs to be the primary.
This seems impossible: before I login this actually works: small one is to the left, big one to the right, big one is primary. But after login its always the other way around: big is left and primary, small is right and secondary. With Nvidia-settings I tried to put everything like I need it, but it always makes the left screen primary and it never saves anything, no matter what I do, so after re login everything is gone anyway. I save to the xorg.conf file every time, press apply every time, nothing works.

How can I put everything the way I want it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be set in nvidia-settings

[image]

Of course you need to save your settings as well ("Save to X configuration file").

If it is not working, likely file a bug report, likely with nvidia.